# Workflow to fire an email

Tags: workflow

I want to create a workflow, which should fire only when i change my pick list value from a particular value to another.

**Example: pick list field status has values a, b, c, d and e. Now i want to send an Email only when the value is changed from B to C .**

What i was trying is

If(isPicklistValue(status__c, 'B'), IF(ischanged(status__c), If(isNow(isPicklistValue(status__c, 'c'), true, false)), false), false)

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it makes use of the `PRIORVALUE` function and here is what it does

if the current value of picklist is c AND if the previous value was b then return true else false.

```
if( AND(ISPICKVAL(status__c,'c'), ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(status__c),'B')),true,false )
```

Comment: Hello Rajiv, thanks for the reply. But i'm getting an error saying, @PRIORVALUE function may not be used in this type of formula.

Comment: what is criteria that you have defined for the worflow? is it "created, and every time it’s edited"?

Comment: yes, i have changed the criteria to "Created, and every time it's edited" and the error was gone. But the workflow is not working.

Comment: also please note the update in the formula, we need to use PRIORVALUE inside ISPICKVAL for picklist value

Comment: After using the PRIORVALUE inside ISPICKVAL for picklist value, the workflow worked.

Comment: glad to know it helped! cheers! :)

Comment: Hello @RajivBhatt i had another requirement that, if the pick value is changed from A to B , 3 days later it should send an email. But because, of the criteria set to created or edited, i am not able to use the above answer. what to do now?

Comment: just a quick thought, how about setting a checkbox as checked when the value changes from A to B (using a workflow rule), and another workflow rule which is time based and sends email 3 days after that checkbox is checked and also resets the checkbox?